# Encoding problems with gulp on Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio, web, character-encoding, gulp

I have several source files in a Visual Studio 2013 wep application project that I process using `gulp` version 3.8.11. Those files are `Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001` encoded text files. After process them, they appear as they were Windows 1252 encoded text files.

For example, given the following `UTF-8 encoded` `src/hello.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, my name is Jesús López</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how it looks on the browser:

[image]

Using the following `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('build', function () {
    gulp.src('src/hello.html')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

After executing `gulp build` on the command line, this is how it looks on the browser:

[image]

How can I solve this encoding problem? Please help.

Comment: This is very interesting. I've looked through `gulp` source code and it doesn't seem possible with gulp 3 to pass in an encoding option to `gulp.src`. You will probably have some luck with some plugin. A quick google search will return many results. I am thinking you should raise this issue with the gulp developers.

Comment: what is your gulp version?

Comment: @Lim H. I I tried with `gulp-convert-encoding` with no luck. I raised an issue on gitub https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1037.

Comment: @Felipe Skinner, version is 3.8.11

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had the same problem with .cshtml files, I found out that it was because of a missing UTF-8 BOM. That can easily be added with a gulp-plugin called gulp-header.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var header = require('gulp-header');

gulp.task('build', function () {
    gulp.src('src/hello.html')
        .pipe(header('\ufeff'));
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Kinda ridiculous we had to do it manually though - I'd expect `dest()` to have a parameter for encoding. Would love to understand the rationale behind the current behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem i solved it by adding

```
var convertEncoding = require('gulp-convert-encoding');

    gulp.task("copy:templates", function () {
        return gulp
            .src("./app/**/*.html")
            .pipe(convertEncoding({ from: "windows1250", to: "utf8" }))
            //.pipe(header('\ufeff'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest("./wwwroot/app"));
    });

    gulp.task('build:ts', function () {

        return gulp.src("./app/**/*.ts")
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(typescript(tsconfigBuildTs))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
            .pipe(convertEncoding({ from: "windows1250", to: "utf8" }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest("./wwwroot/app/"));
    });
```

The most important line is

```
.pipe(convertEncoding({ from: "windows1250", to: "utf8" }))
```

You should check your file encodings for from in the file > advanced save. Mine was set to windows1250 yours might be different.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the previus answer, I do this in my proyect and it run well, but at least in my case I need to put before the other instructions.

This works fine

```
gulp.src(['**/*.html'])
    .pipe(convertEncoding({ from: "windows1250", to: "utf8" }))
    .pipe(replace(/\n\s*\n/g,'\n'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./DIST/'));
```

This doesn't work fine

```
gulp.src(['**/*.html'])
    .pipe(replace(/\n\s*\n/g,'\n'))
    .pipe(convertEncoding({ from: "windows1250", to: "utf8" }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./DIST/'));
```